# How to pass function to component's story?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, storybook

I wanted to add some stories for [vue-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select) component using [Storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook), but I'm struggling with more complicated cases, which involve passing methods.

The method set directly in my components works (it fires `alert('default')`):

```
<template>
    <v-select :on-change="onchangecallback"
              :multiple="multiple"
              v-model="selected" :options="options"></v-select>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import vSelect from 'vue-select'

    Vue.component('v-select', vSelect);

    export default {
        props: {
            options: {
                default: function() { return ['one', 'two'] },
                type: Array
            },
            multiple: {
                default: false,
                type: Boolean
            },
            onchangecallback: {
                default: () => {alert('default')},
                type: Function
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                selected: null
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

but I want to overwrite `onchangecallback` function at one specific story (to fire `alert('custom')`), so I add to my `play/index.js`:

```
storiesOf('VSelect', module)
.add('onchangeCallback', () => ({
        components: {VSelect},
        template:   `<v-select />`,
        methods:    {
            onchangecallback: function() {
                // not sure if I need a function returning a function, so I use both
                alert('custom'); // never fired

                return function() {
                    alert('custom'); // never fired
                };
            }
        }
    }))
```

but I still end up with `alert('default')` instead `alert('custom')`, so `onchangecallback` is not overwritten.

At this point I don't even know if I'm passing this method correctly, the way it's designed is so counter-intuitive. I.e. in my component (first code snippet) I export `onchangecallback` in props (and it works) but in [Storybook example](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/blob/173083412abac06f833e9dc995a94608081bc2db/lib/cli/generators/SFC_VUE/template/src/stories/index.js) methods are passed not in props but in methods!

Comment: You probably want to register vSelect in components hook.

Comment: @MahmudAdam but I did (`Vue.component('v-select', vSelect);` in first code snippet). When I do it also in stories/index.js I end up with `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.